# Php multi-dimension array issue

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am new here and also in programming , stuck in a multi-dimensional array  I am posting my question array and expected output array

I have tried to make recursive function but not able to get expected answer

This is question array

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [4] => Array
                (
                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [6] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [7] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [8] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [9] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [11] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [12] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [13] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [14] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [20] => Array
                (

                    [26] => Array
                        (
                            [27] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [28] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [29] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [30] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [48] => Array
                (


                    [53] => Array
                        (
                            [54] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [55] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [56] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [57] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )



        )


    [190] => Array
        (
            [191] => Array
                (

                    [197] => Array
                        (
                            [198] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [199] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [200] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [201] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [202] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [203] => Array
                        (
                            [204] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [205] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [206] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [207] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )
```

I want output like this , I have tried to make recursive function but it also return me the same array . so any help will highly appreciated . Tq

```
 Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [4] => Array
                (
                [0]=> 5
                [1]=> 6
                [3]=> 7
                [4]=> 8
                [5]=> 9
                [6]=> 10
                [7]=> 11
                [8]=> 12
                [9]=> 13
                [10]=> 14

                )

            [20] => Array
                (

                [0]=> 26
                [1]=> 27
                [2]=> 28
                [3]=> 29
                [4]=> 30

                )

            [48] => Array
                (
                [0]=> 53
                [1]=> 54
                [2]=> 55
                [3]=> 56
                [4]=> 57
                )

        )


    [190] => Array
        (
            [191] => Array
                (
                [0]=> 197
                [1]=> 198
                [2]=> 199
                [3]=> 200
                [4]=> 201
                [5]=> 202
                [6]=> 203
                [7]=> 204
                [8]=> 205
                [9]=> 206
                [10]=> 207

                  )

                )

        )
```

I have tried this but getting same array :

```
public function prepareFunction($array)
{

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value) && !empty($value)) {
            $this->getAllNestedChild($value, $key);
        } else {
            $this->global_array[$key][] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $this->global_array;
}


public function getAllNestedChild($array, $direct_connected)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value) && !empty($value)) {
            $this->global_array[$direct_connected][$key] = $value;
            $this->getAllNestedChild($value, $direct_connected);
        } else {
            $this->global_array[$direct_connected][$key] = $value;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I am bothered by the format of the input array. It is so weird. You're sure you cannot prevent it from getting into that disordered state? Besides that, the main PHP function you would need is [array_keys()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php).

Comment: It may be in other order and also more level deep

Comment: You do realize that the wanted output is impossible? You should always have unique array keys. I think that's a typo?

Comment: so you want to make an array, of the array keys inside a multi-dimentional array of empty arrays?

Comment: Sorry @jameson2012 I have updated my question , It was my mistak

Comment: even with your update my comment still stands.  none of your original arrays have any values in them you are just storing the array keys for some inexplicable reason?  Also you haven't posted any code about what you have tried to create the output you want

Comment: Actually it's a client hierarchy , I want to show all user who are directed connected or indirectly connected with parent , I will sum of data of all indirectly connected user and store in directly connected user and send  SMS with quantity .

Comment: show us what u tried, we cant write the code for you

Comment: @A.Marwan  I have posted what i have tried

Comment: @RishikantVishwakarma can you please confirm. Your our will same logic on '190' array as array '3'. Because as per your wanted output it different in array '190' it should combine '197' and '203'. Means like 
        [0]=> 197
        [1]=> 198
        [2]=> 199
        [3]=> 200
        [4]=> 201
        [5]=> 202
        [6]=> 203
        [7]=> 204
        [8]=> 205
        [9]=> 206
        [10]=> 207

Comment: there's got to be a simpler way than this, where are you getting these arrays from?  Why don't you just do a mysql query with a sum and a group by?

Comment: @RP you are right let me update my answer

Comment: @RishikantVishwakarma I have posted my answer.

Comment: @RP just wow, awesome , Thank a lot bro.

Comment: ok, answer is useful for you. You are most welcome.

Comment: @RP if array is 10 level deep how effective this will be ?

Comment: @RishikantVishwakarma if the array is 10 levels deep then we must change this logic. Because it will be so large for this. You must change your logic about that. Because it will be not a proper logic for 10 levels.

Answer (score 3):

Here is code will help you.

```
    <?php

    $array1 = 'your array'

    $array2 = array(); // take a one empty array

    foreach($array1 as $key => $value){
        if(!empty($value)){
            foreach($value as $key1 => $value1){
                if(!empty($value1)){
                    $array2[$key][$key1] = array_keys_multi($value1);
                }else{
                    $array2[$key][$key1] = '';
                }
            }
        }else{
            $array2[$key] = '';
        }
    }

   // function for fetch keys in a single array.
    function array_keys_multi(array $array)
    {
        $keys = array();

        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            $keys[] = $key;

            if (is_array($value)) {
                $keys = array_merge($keys, array_keys_multi($value));
            }
        }

        return $keys;
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($array2);
```

For check and run my code http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/60b5b29e605b692c8f01114b9950a2d55fe3ff6a